# How to remove items from an Observable Collection

Tags: wpf, collections, observablecollection

I appologize for the novel but I wanted to explain as much as I have done thus far.

Within my current project I have an application that consumes a service that provides a collection as a `<List>`. Due to how I am using this data in the application I have had to convert this data to an observable collection. This was done so that as the data was selected and moved about the application UI updates would be refreshed using INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged.

Where I am having a challenge now is I have a listbox that is bound to the observable collection within the listbox I have a datatemplate that renders out the items of the collection. This data template contains a button which needs to allow the user to click the button for each item to remove them from the collection. 
The use case for this is a listbox that stores selected name as chosen from a gridview. Once the user has selected names from the gridview they are stored ( within the observable collection as a queue) and rendered out in the UI in a listbox control which shows all selected names.  I need to provide the user with the ability to remove these names in any order selected.

From what I have been reading there is no means to enumerate / index an observable collection. For situations such as this you should use List or an Array. However in order for the items to refresh in the list view they need to be in an Observable Collection.
From what I have read it appears that when the event is triggered I need to convert the observable collection to an Array and then evaluate the array to determine the index and then remove the record accordingly?

I think I may be off base on this as it seems like I am over engineering this problem?  The above scenario does not seem correct is because I fell as if I am doing a lot of converting to and from the collections to just remove a record?
Does anyone know of an efficient means to remove records from a collection ( in any order selected) when the collection is rendered out as an items control within a listbox?
I’ve been successful in removing the last record added to the collection using RemoveAt() however I have not had any success in randomly removing records.

*Afterthought:* Part of this issue could be related to the fact that I have a button inserted within the datatemplate (control item) and as a result the item is not actually being selected before the event is fired on the button event?
Sorry for the rambling on this but I have had my head in this for hours and made minor progress. Any tips or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: This question is way too ramble-y. You'll do it justice if you can pare down to an actual question. And FYI, I have no idea where you read you can't index or enumerate an ObservableCollection. Of course you can, it has all the `ICollection<T>` methods (IndexOf, an Item indexer, etc).

Comment: Thanks Adam and yeah sorry for the long novel. I tried to give an overly descriptive question and it came out more confusing that concise. thanks again for the tips on ICollection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668613.aspx) inherits from [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) which implements [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx), so you can certainly index and enumerate it.  It has a [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413.aspx) method that takes the object to remove and removes the first occurrence in the collection and a [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414.aspx) method that takes an index and removes the item at that index.

Based on your afterthought, it sounds like you have a WPF ListBox with an ItemTemplate that creates a Button.  ListBox will set the DataContext of each instantiated template to the item in the list being bound to, so you can get a reference to the item that created a Button from the DataContext property on the Button or by using a Binding.

Comment: Thank you Quarermeister. After some additional research I went back and re-worked the template and removed the button from the template. This allowed me to then use SelectedItem from control and I moved the button to underneath the list. While a little differnt visually. It works with no issues. Thanks for the tip.